# java and nlp to extract information (malware names) and filtering

Tags: java, nlp, filtering

I have been thinking and working on a homemade algorithm to extract malware names from a dataset. The results were not so promising.

My dataset looks like this:

```
torrentlocker payment site
win32/somoto.e potentially unwanted
financial services;malicious sources/malnets;personal sites
tv/video streams;piracy/copyright concerns;entertainment;malicious     sources/malnets
locky;malware;dark;stealing;infected
```

What I would like to have as output is:

```
torrentlocker payment site -> torrentlocker
win32/somoto.e potentially unwanted -> win32/somoto.e
financial services;malicious sources/malnets;personal sites -> null 
tv/video streams;piracy/copyright concerns;entertainment;malicious sources/malnets -> null 
locky;malware;dark;stealing;infected -> locky
```

In general the approach that I think may work is to extract the words with meanings (copyright, payment site, unwanted...). Maybe there is an easy way (better than scraping a online dictionary) to have all the words with meaning and then compare them with my data? I found through searching that NLP (natural language processing) is a way to do it. I would like to have some recommendations if there's a better way to do this, especially that I prefer working with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is known as Named Entity Recognition (NER). There are several open source libraries available for NER, such as Stanford NLPs NER system found here https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html. It's all in Java too.

If you can put together a reasonably large training set you should be able to train a model using Stanford's NER implementation.

Comment: However i would like if you can elaborate a little bit based on the examples i gave in my question

Comment: You would have to manually tag the dataset you have to indicate which token is of the desired output entity type. I believe CoreNLP uses the ConLL format for this. You would then train a model based on this labeled data. You can read more through the link above.

Comment: @devrj just curious, is there anything missing for you to consider this answer acceptable? :)

Comment: I upvoted it and forgot to accepted it as i was waiting for other answers.  Thank you for the reminder